# How to make a wooden needle?

Tags: woodworking

I am recently exploring a new craft: [Nålebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A5lebinding). I started using regular large plastic needles. But sadly, these are a little bit too small and soft for this craft, so the eyelets often break.

I have seen people using needles made from bone, antler or wood. Since I live in a woody area, I would like to know if anybody has experience in making needles from wood? It would have to look something like this:

[image]

I have some small woodworking tools, but I have never used them. They were a gift from somebody else that gave up on woodworking after not succeeding a few times.

So, my questions basically are:

- What is a good sort of wood to make a needle from?
- How do I start? Do I make the eyelet first, or the needle shape?
- Are there any things that I, as an absolute beginner, should be aware of?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if you haven't already, I would check out the Society for Creative Anachronism and see if they have any resources available to help answer some of your questions.  It is a group that is focused on medieval reenactments, and I myself learned naalbinding from members of the group. I know many of them make their own tools, so they may have resources that can help you if no one here is able to answer.

Comment: Suggestion: bamboo. That sort of flat strips from which tweezers are made should be pretty good for this.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**: I've never actually made a needle for naalbinding, but I have done some other wood carving and the principles are the same.

[The site from which you (presumably) got your picture](http://www.en.neulakintaat.fi/19) lists a few materials that naalbinding needles can and have been made from, including the following:

- juniper
- rowan tree
- honeysuckle
- lilac
- olive tree
- fruit trees (like apple tree)
- ice cream sticks

From the above, you can probably conclude that any reasonable wood (I.E. not balsa) will do.

I found [a tutorial](http://pin.it/zXvNLx-) that suggests making the basic shape first, but given that making the eye is probably the trickiest bit I would make it first before carving the shape.

As always, the main thing to be aware of is safety. If using a knife, **always cut away from you**, and take appropriate steps with whatever other equipment you may use.

Apart from that, the only thing that's required is a small amount of (what looks to be very cheap) material and some practice.